# VS 2017 PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'v15\\Server\\sqlite3\\db.lock'

Tags: docker, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, docker-compose, azure-service-fabric

While working on a ServiceFabric based solution and building a docker image I am getting the following because of my directory structure :

My directory structure is

```
D:
  D1:
    src:
      Foo.Fabric:                          
        Foo.Fabric:                      -----------------> This is context right now
          .vs
        Foo.Service:
          DockerFile
          Foo.Service.csproj
        docker-compose.yml
        .dockerignore
      Foo.Lib:
        Foo.Lib:
          Foo.Lib.csproj
```

The content of my docker-compose.yml is like :

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  foo:
    image: foodockerimage
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Foo.Service/Dockerfile
```

And the content of my dockerfile is as follows

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY Foo.Service/Foo.Service.csproj Foo.Service/
COPY ../Foo.Lib/Foo.Lib/Foo.Lib.csproj ../Foo.Lib/Foo.Lib/
RUN dotnet restore Foo.Service/Foo.Service.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Foo.Service
RUN dotnet build Foo.Service.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish Foo.Service.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Foo.Service.dll"]
```

As we can see here clearly that I need to build this Lib.csproj along with my main Foo.Service.csproj The problem is the directory location of Lib project. Becuase this is used by some other solutions, I can not not move this Lib project inside the Foo.Fabric folder.

Now initially I got the error of "Service 'foo' failed to build: COPY failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../Foo.Lib/Foo.Lib/Foo.Lib.csproj", OK I got this, I have a wrong context so I updated in docker-compose.yml as 
build: context: . to build: context: ..
to change the context to the parent directory of the current directory, so again I will have to change the paths of dockerfile resulting a docker-compose.yml as

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  foo:
    image: foodockerimage
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: Foo.Fabric/Foo.Service/Dockerfile
```

And also

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY Foo.Fabric/Foo.Service/Foo.Service.csproj Foo.Fabric/Foo.Service/  #Updated
COPY Foo.Lib/Foo.Lib/Foo.Lib.csproj Foo.Lib/Foo.Lib/  #Updated
RUN dotnet restore Foo.Service/Foo.Service.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Foo.Service
RUN dotnet build Foo.Service.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish Foo.Service.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Foo.Service.dll"]
```

Now I have this error "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '\\?\D:\D1\src\Foo.Fabric\.vs\Foo.Fabric\v15\Server\sqlite3\db.lock'"

I am really banging my haed with this and couldn't get up. 
By the way I am using :

Docker Desktop Community Version 2.0.0.0-win81(29211) Engine: 18.09.0

Visual Studio Professional 2017 15.9.3

Windows 10 1809

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure to exclude the .vs folder from your build, by using a '.dockerignore' file next to the dockerfile. Usually they look like this, for VS projects:

```
.dockerignore
.env
.git
.gitignore
.vs
.vscode
docker-compose.yml
docker-compose.*.yml
*/bin
*/obj
```

Comment: Yes, it has to be right next to the Dockerfile that fails to build. It doesn't appear to work like .gitignore for instance,

Comment: If you are using `docker-compose` with a service referring to an existing docker image, then you can put the `.dockerignore` file next to the docker-compose file. I've run into a similar issue but am not using `Dockerfile`.